# Converting a Certificate Signing Request public key from ECDSA to RSA

Tags: ssl-certificate, rsa, ecdsa, applepayjs, heroku-ssl

I am working on an application hosted on Heroku that communicates with an apple system that requires SSL certificates to be in place. Apple requires that an ECC certificate be used where Heroku does not support ECC certificates - only RSA.

I am curious to know if I can generate my signing request with an ECC signature and use this to generate the certificate from apple but then convert this ECC key to an RSA key so that Heroku can still interpret this.

Do I have a drastic misunderstanding of how these two certificates are implemented that means this approach is not possible or do I just need to do the right openSSL commands to the cert to generate the key formats I need?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your system and I'm skeptical that Apple requires ECC certificates, but as best as I understand your question, no, you cannot "convert" ECC keys into RSA keys or vice-versa.

Comment: When using Apple Pay (JS) anytime I upload an RSA Signed Cert Request in order to generate the apple payment processing cert it says I need to use ECC signed 256 bit. I have researched this topic a little more and realize it would be a moot point since I would need apple to use RSA signatures indefinitely for this to work. Sadly, Heroku just doesn't support these yet